# Azure devops web extension show loading indicator post SDK.notifyLoadSucceeded()

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am opening a [modal dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=Check%20out%20our%20newest%20documentation,until%20the%20dialog%20is%20dismissed.) on clicking the context menu. After initial loading, I want to load some more data based on the user's input on the dialog. While loading this data, I want to show a similar loading indicator that is displayed at the very beginning before we invoke `SDK.notifyLoadSucceeded()`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What about using [Spinner](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/Spinner)？ Use this control when loading the data, and remove that after the data is loaded completely.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT That can be an alternative. Is there no way to display the default loading indicator? I can see that indicator being used at multiple places on dev.azure.com. for e.g. when adding remote related link to a work item.